# Selenium: Scrape Data From Newly Opened Tab

Tags: python, selenium

I'm scraping data from a page that has 20 links on it, each link opens an identically formatted new tab. Selenium clicks on the first link, which opens in a new tab, but then attempts to scrape from the initial tab.

Relevant code:

```
for y in range(1):
    table = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@summary='Sections']//tbody")
    rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr') 
    for row in rows:
        if row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
            linktext = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[3].text
            print(linktext)
            browser.find_element_by_link_text(linktext).click()
            time.sleep(5)
            title = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@id='VAR1']").text
            section = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@id='VAR2']").text
            description = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@id='VAR3']").text
```

This code fails on the `title = browser...` line because it can't find the xpath. I confirmed that the xpath `("//p[@id='VAR1']")` exists on the newly opened tab. If I instead use an xpath that exists only on the main page (not the newly opened tab), then that line succeeds and the error moves to the `sections =...` line.

**How do I redirect Selenium to scrape the newly opened tab?** And once I've done that, I'm assuming I'll need to redirect it back to its initial tab to click the next link, or at a minimum close the newly opened tab.

Comment: [this](https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903) may be relevant to you. It describes a process for shifting focus to the new tab, then shifting back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to switch window frames on driver.

```
driver.switch_to.window.(driver.window_handles[-1]);
```

Switching to the last window handle will switch to the most recently opened window.

Comment: perhaps you meant  `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])`

Comment: It depends on the language. Some have built in list operator methods such as `Last()`. But `[-1]` is functionally the same.

Comment: the question was tagged Python